# How do I make an Cross Domain Request with Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, cors

I've been asked to get some "data" from an xml feed and to add it to a page I am hosting on my server.  I figured I'd use the jQuery Ajax api -- and I'm getting this error.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load .../3.atom. Origin http://myserver.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Do I need to request access from someone?  Is there something I can add to my request?  I've read stuff about CORS, is that a service I should use in this case?

Here's my code at the moment.

```
var feedUrl = "http://www.holmanreviews.com/audi-pembroke-pines/3.atom";
var content;

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: feedUrl,
    dataType: "xml",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (xml) {
        $(xml).find('entry').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var id = $this.attr('id');
            content += id;
        });
    }
});

$('#feed').append(content);
```

I have a JS FIddle here as well. http://jsfiddle.net/rsturim/6nsyX/

Would love some background on this if you can help -- thanks a bunch.

Comment: you'll need to use JSONP...

Comment: JSONP, CORS, or a server-side proxy.

Comment: Are you in control of the remote domain or not? That severely restricts your options.

Comment: I am not in control of the remote domain :(

Comment: I wouldn't suggest CORS if you wish to use jQuery to make the request and want full IE support (cors can't work in IE7, and jQuery doesn't support CORS requests in IE8 and 9). Server-side proxy would be an easier way to do it. Just request the data with your server, and have your page request it from your server instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably going to need to set up a [server-side proxy](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html) in order to access this data.

CORS won't work because you are not in control of the server.

JSON-P won't work because the server doesn't seem to accept a "callback" parameter. I tested this by appending "?callback=foo" to your request url, which did not change the response. It is possible that their API supports some other name for the callback parameter, but its hard to know without seeing any documentation for their API.

Answer (score 1):

You were making the request correctly but the remote site would need to support CORS and the error you're receiving means it does not support it.

Since it's an Atom feed, there's probably not much chance the remote site supports JSONP so your best approach is to use a proxy. And instead of rolling your own you can use Yahoo's YQL to fetch either XML or JSON. YQL does support CORS so you can get either.

XML:

> [`http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.holmanreviews.com%2Faudi-pembroke-pines%2F3.atom%22%20and%20itemPath%3D%22feed.entry%22&format=xml`](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20xml%20where%20url=%22http://www.holmanreviews.com/audi-pembroke-pines/3.atom%22%20and%20itemPath=%22feed.entry%22&format=xml)

JSON:

> [`http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.holmanreviews.com%2Faudi-pembroke-pines%2F3.atom%22%20and%20itemPath%3D%22feed.entry%22&format=json`](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20xml%20where%20url=%22http://www.holmanreviews.com/audi-pembroke-pines/3.atom%22%20and%20itemPath=%22feed.entry%22&format=json)

XML will give you exactly what you would've got from the site directly, but it's not much fun to parse XML with JavaScript, so I highly recommend using the JSON. (You could also get JSONP but JSON with CORS support is better.)

From your code I'm pretty sure you're capable of building these URLs from the basic URL so I'll leave that as an exercise (-;

---

Oh if you really need to support Internet Explorer versions earlier than 10, or any other browser that doesn't support CORS, here's a neat way to use CORS when the browser supports it and JSONP otherwise:

```
dataType: $.support.cors ? "json" : "jsonp"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JSONP for this. It's a nice trick to break same origin policies. It is very dangerous, so you have to trust the data's provider.

Use the related dataType in your request config:

```
dataType: "xml"
```

Additionally, your feed needs to support JSONP. This means, if the request URL is suffixed by a query like callback=?, the response must be wrapped in a Javascript function and quotes need to be esacaped:

```
callback("<your-xml>...</your-xml>");
```

This is the basic idea of JSONP. If you want to understand why you have to it this way just have look at the Wikipedia article for examle: [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)